# Vue Plugin Development

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, vue-cli

I am developing my own vue-plugin. It contains some globalErrorHandler and one Vue.mixins method.
For testing reasons i created a folder plugin and imported the functions into my main.js (`import pluginVue from './plugins/pluginVue'` & `Vue.use(pluginVue)`).
Everything works for me so far. Now i want to oursource the plugin folder and create a Vue Plugin. I looked up the "Vue Plugin Development" and found some nice information. But I dont know, which files i really need, like index.js, generator.js, prompts.js,... . I also have no clue how to implement my written code, for example: in which file do i have to add my code and can i just copy & paste it?! Does someone of you have some experience with creating an vue plugin?

My pluginVue so far:

```
const pluginVue = {}

pluginVue.install = function (Vue){

Vue.config.errorHandler = function(err, vm,  info) {
const information = {
"timestamp": new Date(),
"err": err.name ,
"message": msg,
 }

 const jsonString = JSON.stringify(information);
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/backend");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonString);

  })
    };

Vue.onerror = async function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
const information = {
"timestamp": new Date(),
"message": msg,
"source": source , "lineno": lineno ,"colno": colno , "error": err.name
 }

 const jsonString = JSON.stringify(information);
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/backend");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(jsonString);
    console.log(jsonString);

  })

}

Vue.mixin({
   methods: {
    Thrower(optionals, msg){
      ...
    }
   },
  });
 }

 export default pluginVue;
```